# Unable to read the Content of Email Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I am reading the incoming mails from a outlook mailbox using automation anywhere **Email Automation - Get All Messages** menu. My simple code is given below. But everytime I am getting html objects and tags printing in the message box, I want only the email message.

```
Start Loop "Each message on server:outlook.office.365.com,User Name:xyz@xyz.com,SSL Server Type:POP3,Message Format:Plain Text"
    Message Box:"$Email Message$"
```

Can anyone help????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original Email Automation - Get All Messages command, there should be a "Message Format" option below port number.

If not - you could offload to a javascript script that might look like this and call it via Run Script:

```
function noTags(vString) {
    return vString.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
}
```

Passing vString into it and getting vString back out, now without the tags.